# How do I give a WordPress Custom Menu item an id or class for CSS targeting?

Tags: css, wordpress

I created a custom menu item in Appearance > Menus and would like to be able to specifically target it with CSS; however, I don't know how to assign it an id or class? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try reading the [codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu), you can pass two parameters to you [wp_nav_menu](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu) call. One for menu_id and one for menu_class.

As Lollero said above, the menu items themselves will automatically have class's and ID's given to them.

Answer (score 3):

Im not super familiar with the menu creation that way.

But when you create a new page it will automatically get class that points to the page with its ID.

for example:

```
.page_item .page-item-5
```

and the last number(s) represents the id of the page. Which you can check from the page edit section in the admin panel.

( edit: it was like five in the morning and i missed that theres actually 2 classes. Regular and specific. Also this is a `<li>` tag which contains the `<a>` tag

---

Note that there is also

```
.current_page_item
```

which is automatically created.